# create a copy of a windows phone project in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

I've developed a "basic app" which has a bunch of features. from that app i want to create copies of the same app and then customize them and build different apps. for example: think of a basic app for restaurants, all the restaurant app will have the "menu" page but everyone will have different menus and other differences.

I've tried to copy-paste the project folder and then add the project to the solution, but in this way I've to refactor all the files manually....

how can i make several copies of the app (possibly with auto-refactoring)?
it's possible to create the copies in new solutions?

thanks

Comment: You can export a Project-template, did you try that?  But refactoring (renaming) stays manual. Only the Project name is applied.

Comment: ok, how can i do this?

I've tried the automatic refactoring but visualstudio also refactor the original project
what if i create a new solution, import the project and use automatic refactor? could it work? (however i don't know how to create a new solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved doing those steps:
1)create an empty project (and solution)
2)make a copy in the new solution of the old project folder
3)add the copy to the new solution
4)refactor